# HTML closing tags are modified after retrieving from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I use laravel to retrieve some raw html from mysql database.

The problem is that data is modified after I retrieve it.

**Data in database:**

```
<p>888</p>
```

**After retrieval:**

```
<p>888<\/p>
```

**Laravel method used for retrieval:**

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::All();
        echo $posts;
    }
```

Any idea why it is happening and how to solve it ?

Data type for this column in the database is medumtext.

Thanks.

Comment: The char `/` is like a "special" char, like the `\n` on C# for line breaks. So, in this case, you receive an `\\` to tell that this next char is a literal char, not the special char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` Slash is a special character.
In order to fix ur issue use `stripslashes()`

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::All();
    echo stripslashes($posts);
}
```